# How to access variables in object JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```js
  const renameKeysButton = () => {
    let v1 = document.querySelectorAll('.renameKeysInput')[0].value;
    let v2 = document.querySelectorAll('.renameKeysInput')[1].value;
    let v3 = document.querySelectorAll('.renameKeysInput')[2].value;
    let obj = { v1: 'Bobo', v2: 'Programmer', v3: 100 };
    console.log(renameKey({ name: 'firstName', job: 'Actor' }, obj));
  }

  let renameKey = (keyObj, obj) => {
  let result = {}
    for (let key in obj) {
      result[keyObj[key] || key] = obj[key]
    }
    return result
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="renameKeysInput" value="A">
<input type="text" class="renameKeysInput" value="B">
<input type="text" class="renameKeysInput" value="C">
<button onclick='renameKeysButton()'>Try</button>
```

I want to change the keys in `obj` with the keys in `keyobj`. I put variables in `obj` to get values from HTML input but it cannot access them and show v1, v2 , v3 insted of A, B, C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use array notation to assign the values to the object. That way, you can get the properties' names from `v1`, `v2` and `v3`. It should look like this:

```js
  const renameKeysButton = () => {
    let v1 = document.querySelectorAll('.renameKeysInput')[0].value;
    let v2 = document.querySelectorAll('.renameKeysInput')[1].value;
    let v3 = document.querySelectorAll('.renameKeysInput')[2].value;
    let obj = {};
    obj[v1] = 'Bobo';
    obj[v2] = 'Programmer';
    obj[v3] = 100;
    console.log(renameKey({ name: 'firstName', job: 'Actor' }, obj));
  }

  let renameKey = (keyObj, obj) => {
    let result = {}
    for (let key in obj) {
      result[keyObj[key] || key] = obj[key]
    }
    return result
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="renameKeysInput" value="A">
<input type="text" class="renameKeysInput" value="B">
<input type="text" class="renameKeysInput" value="C">
<button onclick='renameKeysButton()'>Try</button>
```

Comment: When you use `v1`, `v2` and `v3` as object keys, javascript interprets them literally. It doesn't get their values, but uses their names directly. If you want javascript to get their values to use them as keys, you have to put them between brackets like I did in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You are never putting the actual values inside the `obj` object.
Put the 'v1','v2' & 'v3' variables into it.
Also, you need to declare `renameKey` before using it. If not function hoisting with a vanilla function.

```
  let renameKey = (keyObj, obj) => {
  let result = {}
    for (let key in obj) {
      result[keyObj[key] || key] = obj[key]
    }
    return result
  }

const renameKeysButton = () => {
    let v1 = document.querySelectorAll('.renameKeysInput')[0].value;
    let v2 = document.querySelectorAll('.renameKeysInput')[1].value;
    let v3 = document.querySelectorAll('.renameKeysInput')[2].value;
    // 
    let obj = { v1: v1, v2: v2, v3: v3 };
    console.log(renameKey({ name: 'firstName', job: 'Actor' }, obj));
  }

<input type="text" class="renameKeysInput" value="A">
<input type="text" class="renameKeysInput" value="B">
<input type="text" class="renameKeysInput" value="C">
<button onclick='renameKeysButton()'>Try</button>
```

Comment: Do you mean that i cannot set variables to keys but i can set variables to values?

Comment: Variables and values are the same thing in this context. `let v1` is `A` and you need to put it into `obj`. Also the key is on the left side inside `obj`